# SQL to return duplicate rows with one column

Tags: c#, sql

I am looking for some simple sql  to convert a simple sql query which will return me some column values like this

```
select ab,cd,ef,gh from alphabets
```

which returns me

```
ab  cd  ef  gh
--------------
a   b   c   d
```

what I actually want is to append something to this query that will return me same record but certain number of times with one differing value.

```
ab  cd  ef  gh
--------------
a   b   x    d
a   b   y    d
a   b   z    d
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

P.S. If anyone be able to show it how to do it in c# with sql mapping to object will be useful as well.Thanks alot.

Comment: Why? How many times? Are `x, y, z` in that order because of the number of rows?

Comment: why? I need to compare this object with some other object which contains multiple items but based on columns with different values. How many times? could be any number (no union with selects) and No particular order x,y, z is just to show different values.

Comment: Where does `x,y,z` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Well ok, here's some SQL magic.

```
declare @alphabets table (ab varchar, cd varchar, ef varchar, gh varchar)
insert @alphabets values ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

select a.ab, a.cd, xyz.ef, a.gh
from 
    @alphabets a,
    (select 'x' ef union all 
     select 'y' ef union all
     select 'z' ef ) xyz
```

This is just using an (implicit) cross join to get the cartesian product of the single `@alphabets` row and the three `xyz` rows.

Answer (score 1):

You've not stated where the values 'x', 'y' and 'z' come from, but typically this would be from another table.  In which case, let's make another table and join them in a way that every row in the 2nd table joins with the same row in the table that you have described:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ab varchar(1), cd varchar(1), ef varchar(1), gh varchar(1))
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (zz varchar(1))
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES ('x'),('y'),('z')

SELECT ab, cd, ef, zz 
FROM @Table1 T1
INNER JOIN @Table2 T2 ON 1=1
```

Result:

```
ab | cd | ef | zz
-----------------
a  | b  | c  | x
a  | b  | c  | y
a  | b  | c  | z
```